# Send to C:\<copy path>\Develop batch

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Using Windows 10 if possible, I'd like to be able to send from my local host to my git development path using the Send To context menu.

> (Win + R, shell:sendto)

I have two directories lets say they are:

C:\wamp\www\projectname
C:\Users\myname\projectname

Now lets say I've updated a file deep in my localhost directory e.g.

C:\wamp\www\projectname\application\libraries\js\jsfile.js

I'd like to be able to right click that file > Send to

Dev root path: (C:\Users\myname\projectname) append file path (\application\libraries\js\jsfile.js)

So essentially it's sending the file to the same folder, just in a different directory.

I can get some of the path using:

```
for /f %%q in ("%~dp0.") do echo C:\Users\myname\projectname\%%~nxq
```

I'd need to get all folders after \projectname\ and that could be 1 or 10 different folders.

I realize this a lot to ask but I think this could be useful for many people.

Comment: Would you like to do this with all files in C:\wamp\www\projectname\application\ or just the ones you right click + send to ? Cause if you want all you could use robocopy Source Destiny /e that would automatically create all subfolders that do not exist in the destiny...

Comment: Just the selected files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be as expected:

[image]

My Project.bat:

```
@echo off

set Destiny=%userprofile%\projectname
set PartToIgnore=\wamp\www\projectname\application\

IF /i not exist "%Destiny%" md "%Destiny%"

for %%a in (%*) do call :MoveFiles "%%~a"
exit

:MoveFiles
set SourceFile=
set RelativeSource=
set "SourceFile=%~pnx1"
call set "RelativeSource=%%SourceFile:%PartToIgnore%=%%"
echo F | xcopy /i /h /y "%~1" "%Destiny%\%RelativeSource%"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Amazing, you just made my life much easier! Thank you.